# Djangocms show_menu not stable according browser version and type

Tags: menu, navigation, show, django-cms

Platform Django 1.9.9 Djangocms 3.3.2 Linux Fedora 22 (Local server) or Centos(Remote server)

The code is below, the trouble is about the **show_menu** tag. According to the local client OS and navigator, it works correctly or it disappears (The html code is not created)

- With Client Fedora 22 and Firefox 48.02 it works on local and remote
- With Client Fedora 22 and Opera 39 it works on local not on remote
- with Fedora 22 and Chrome 52 it does not work on local and remote
- With Client windows 10 and Opera 39 it does not work
- With Client Windows 10 and Firefox 48.02 it does not work
- With Client Windows 10 and Internet Explorer it does not work
- With Client Windows 10 and Chrome 52 it does not work
- With Client Windows 10 and Firefox 48.02 it does not work
- with client Ubuntu 16.02 and mozilla it works
- with client Ubuntu 16.02 and Opera 39 it does not works

On show_menu tag  from djangocms
Inside the Nav container I've the following code in my base.html template :

```
enter {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="falsecode here">{{ user.username }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="{% url "crud_volunteer" %}">Liste bénévoles</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "crud_structure" %}">Liste structures</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "crud_training" %}">Liste formations</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "crud_book" %}">Liste livres</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "crud_convention" %}">Liste conventions</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "crud_event" %}">Liste évènements</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "post_new" %}">Suggestions</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/">Administration</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url "lfl66_logout" %}">Déconnexion</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
     {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
</ul>
enter
```

`{% else %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- SHOW-MENU -->
        {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="{% url "lfl66_login" %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" style ="width: 80px;" class="form-control" name="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" style ="width: 80px;" class="form-control" name="password">
      </div>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Entrez!</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}`

> The menu.html is the standard one, sent with DjangoCms. 
>   When the tag **show_menu** works correctly the producted HTML code is as below. Without the menu.html template, as you know, the class "dropdown-menu" is removed. When Trouble all this code is not produced.
>
> :

```
<li class="active dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            LFL66 <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

`<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="">
            <a href="/cms/presentation/"><span>Accueil</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="/cms/activite-locales/"><span>Actions locales</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="/cms/structures/"><span>L'association</span></a>

    </li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="/cms/financement/"><span>Financement</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>`

All ideas, hints advices are welcome, It can be a stupid mistake on my side, I check settings, path, release, middleware .... So thanks for help

Marcel Bariou

Comment: Hello Marcel, the show_menu tag has no logic for browser types. I think you're being cached. Try turning off all caching to test.

Comment: Thanks @paulo, about show_menu tag, it is ok I know, about cache I've done that. More about, the first time viewing the remote website I've immediately the error, with Opera, and all navigators on Windows 10, but not on Ubuntu and Linux Fedora 22 for Firefox only.